# Probability on Hilbert spaces

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, hilbert-spaces

I have been looking to generalize a result concerning random variables with values in $\mathbb{R}^d$ to random variable with values in function spaces (in particular a space of smooth functions). I noticed that expressing many of my conditions in the $\mathbb{R}^d$-case as norms and inner-products made it very easy to translate my results into the functional case. It seemed very well-behaved, so I pondered if maybe further generalization was possible.

Does anyone have a reference about probability theory on Hilbert spaces in general, i.e. how to define/calculate expectations, variances, covariances of Hilbert space valued random variables? I'm very familiar with measure theory and probability theory but not very solid on heavy functional analysis / topology.

I'd like to avoid thinking of stochastic processes as indexed families of regular random variables but instead view them as points in some function space (Hilbert space) and then use the tools of the function space to do probability. Maybe this isn't possible and it is just wishful thinking from me but a solid book or two would be much appreciated!

Comment: Off the top of my head, there is a short chapter or so at the start of "Stochastic Equations in Infinite Dimensions" by Da Prato & Zabczyk covering some stuff on probability for random variables valued in a separable Banach space (more if you're interested in the Gaussian case). Without the separability assumption, measure theory in infinite dimensional spaces is badly behaved so I'd guess you'll end up wanting this. There will of course be other more complete sources, this is just a pointer that immediately came to mind.

Comment: @RhysSteele Thanks, I gave it a quick look, its definitely close to what I want but is perhaps a little brief in its exposition.

Comment: K. R. Parthasarathy, _Probability Measures on Metric Spaces_ has a chapter on Hilbert space.  See the review by R. M. Dudley, https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177697834